# TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable int object (Python)

Tags: python, list

I am trying to add `(0.5,-0.5)` to `(i,j)` elements in the list `I4` but there is an error. I present the expected output.

```
I3 = [[(0, 0), (0, 1)], [(0, 0), (1, 0)], [(0, 1), (1, 1)], [(1, 0), (1, 1)]]
temp = []
for t in range(0,len(I3)):
    I4 = [(j, -i) for i, j in I3[t]]
    temp.append(I4)
print("I4 =",temp)
#I4 = [[(0, 0), (1, 0)], [(0, 0), (0, -1)], [(1, 0), (1, -1)], [(0, -1), (1, #-1)]]

temp2 = []
for h in range(0,len(I3)):
    I5 = [(i+0.5, j-0.5) for i, j in I4[h]]
    temp2.append(I5)
print("I5 =",temp2)
```

The error is

```
in <listcomp>
    I5 = [(i+0.5, j-0.5) for i, j in I4[h]]

TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable int object
```

The expected output is

```
I5 = [[(0.5, -0.5), (1.5, -0.5)], [(0.5, -0.5), (0.5, -1.5)], [(1.5, -0.5), (1.5, -1.5)], [(0.5, -1.5), (1.5, -1.5)]]
```

Comment: Note that it wasn't clear in your description that you swapper i,j to j,i too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seems to misunderstand a thing `print("I4 =",temp)`, `I4` was just ONE element you added to `temp`,  And you heave repeated the mistake later

```
I5 = [(i+0.5, j-0.5) for i, j in I4[h]]    # error
I5 = [(i+0.5, j-0.5) for i, j in temp[h]]  # correct
                                  ^
```

---

You can use a better naming, iteration on value, and avoid variable that you can inline easily, that can fail you to right propre (as you did with `I4`)

```
temp = []
for sublist in I3:
    temp.append([(j, -i) for i, j in sublist])

temp2 = []
for sublist in temp:
    temp2.append([(i + 0.5, j - 0.5) for i, j in sublist])
```

You can use list comprehension

```
temp = [[(j, -i) for i, j in sublist] for sublist in I3]
temp2 = [[(i + 0.5, j - 0.5) for i, j in sublist] for sublist in temp]
```

You can use **one** list comprehension

```
result = [[(j + 0.5, -i - 0.5) for i, j in sublist] for sublist in I3]
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems to be failing due to a misplaced `#` character on `I4` list and a wrong iteration over `I4`, which should be `I3` instead:

```
I3 = [[(0, 0), (0, 1)], [(0, 0), (1, 0)], [(0, 1), (1, 1)], [(1, 0), (1, 1)]]
temp = []
for t in range(0,len(I3)):
    I4 = [(j, -i) for i, j in I3[t]]
    temp.append(I4)
print("I4 =",temp)

temp2 = []
for h in range(0,len(I3)):
    I5 = [(i+0.5, j-0.5) for i, j in I3[h]]
    temp2.append(I5)
print("I5 =",temp2)
```

**Output:**

```
I4 = [[(0, 0), (1, 0)], [(0, 0), (0, -1)], [(1, 0), (1, -1)], [(0, -1), (1, -1)]]
I5 = [[(0.5, -0.5), (1.5, -0.5)], [(0.5, -0.5), (0.5, -1.5)], [(1.5, -0.5), (1.5, -1.5)], [(0.5, -1.5), (1.5, -1.5)]]
```

Comment: You share an "output" so you have executed the code right ?

Comment: @azro Yes, I run it on Google Colab. You can test the output too

Comment: I have tested it, that isn't the output the code gives, and that is normal because a mistake persists in the code you show

Comment: @azro Wait, I think I missed something on the code.

Answer (score 0):

The second part of the code should be

```
for h in range(0,len(I3)):
    I5 = [(i+0.5, j-0.5) for i, j in temp[h]]
    temp2.append(I5)

print("I5 =",temp2)
```

Replace `I4` with `temp` should solve the issue here.